# Vala: How do I print a object to stdout

Tags: vala

I'm trying to inspect an object to see what properties it has. Is there a method to print an object to the stdout?

Answer (score 3):

There is no method to convert an object into a string. You can do `((ObjectClass) obj.get_type().class_ref()).list_properties()` to inspect the properties of a class (not all the fields though, only properties). You might like something like this:

```
public void type_info<T>() {
    var type = typeof(T);
    TypeQuery query;
    type.query(out query);
    stdout.printf("%s %c%c%c%C%C%C%C%C%C%C%C size(class = %u instance = %u)\n", type.name(),
        type.is_object() ? 'o' : '-',
        type.is_abstract() ? 'a' : '-',
        type.is_classed() ? 'c' : '-',
        type.is_derivable() ? (type.is_deep_derivable() ? 'D' : 'd') : '-',
        type.is_derived() ? 'v' : '-',
        type.is_fundamental() ? 'F' : '-',
        type.is_instantiatable() ? 'N' : '-',
        type.is_interface() ? 'i' : '-',
        type.is_value_type() ? 's' : '-',
        type.is_enum() ? 'e' : '-',
        type.is_flags() ? 'f' : '-',
        query.class_size,
        query.instance_size);

    if (type.is_object()) {
        stdout.printf("class %s", type.name());
        for(var parent = type.parent(); parent != Type.INVALID; parent = parent.parent()) {
            stdout.printf(" : %s", parent.name());
        }
        stdout.printf(" {\n");
        foreach (var property in ((ObjectClass)type.class_ref()).list_properties()) {
            stdout.printf("\t%s :: %s -- %s\n", property.name, property.value_type.name(), property.get_blurb());
        }
        stdout.printf("}\n");
    }
}
```